# Django Overriding Model Clean() vs Save()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a couple of actions to perform when saving a models, especially from the admin. I capitalize a couple of fields and check to make sure that either one field or the other is filled. I also create the field slug. RIght now these are split between overriding the clean and the save functions. It works now, but I am curious on when to use each. I looked through the docs, and I couldn't find specifically which to use when.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should use clean to do validation-related work, and to parse/change/otherwise clean the input.  Capitalizing fields and generating a slug can happen here.  I also use clean to force a field like `post_type` to a specific value in proxy models.  If you raise `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError('error text')` inside clean, the `'error text'` is added to the  `form.non_field_errors`.

Save is the place to change the way a model is actually saved.  For instance, I've used save to create a crop of an uploaded picture.  `ValidationError`s are not caught if raised here, and I feel like that's the most important practical difference between the two.

Comment: Ah stole the words right off of my keyboard. Nice answer. The only thing I was going to add is a link to the docs where there is a nice example of a `ValidationError` being thrown: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: Not django.forms.ValidationError, but django.core.exceptions.ValidationError

Comment: Good catch. I guess I have just always imported it from forms (which imports it from core.exceptions). Updating the answer.