# Force CharField's Choices

Tags: django, model, django-orm

I have few `models.CharField` objects in my Model, with the `choices` attribute.

This is working great as far as the GUI is concerned, But I want to block values other than these specified in the `choices` attribute in the code itself (to protect myself from bugs).

Is there a way to raise an exception (I believe it'll be a `ValueError`) when trying to save a string which is not in the choices list?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Please clarify that's wrong with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [override the save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) of your model to raise your own exception:

```
class MyModel:

    MY_CHOICES = (
        # choices here
    )

    myfield = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=MY_CHOICES)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        choice = self.myfield
        if not any(choice in _tuple for _tuple in self.MY_CHOICES):
            raise ValueError('An error message.')
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Just seen this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048108/django-overriding-model-clean-vs-save. The clean() method seems the preferred place for form validation, as per Fazil's answer. Also if you raise ValidationError inside clean() it automatically adds it to form.non_field_errors (although this is less relevant if using the 'choices' attribute and related form widget to limit options).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the model clean method for that,

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    CHOICES = ('your_choices_here',)

    def clean(self):
        if not any(self.field_name in item for item in self.CHOICES):
            raise ValueError("Your error message here.")
```